# How to call an if statement during a while loop in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So as a python project I am making a game. So in this game, you enter a coordinate, and the computer says is it the correct one or not. Now the problem is there is a while loop and only after the while loop is done the if statement is called. But I want the if statement to be called after every loop in the while loop.

This is the code

```
r = 0

while r<15:
hit = str(input("A1    A2    A3    A4    A5\n\nB1    B2    B3    B4    B5\n\nC1    C2    C3    C4    
C5\n\nD1    D2    D3    D4    D5\n\nE1    E2    E3    E4    E5\nThis is the board. Pick any co- 
ordinate you want to fire on: "))

    if hit=="A2" or "a2":
        print("You hit on target A2!")
    elif hit=="B3" or "b3":
        print("You hit on target B3!")
    elif hit=="C1" or "c1":
        print("You hit on target C1!")
    elif hit=="C2" or "c2":
        print("You hit on target C2!")
    elif hit=="D5" or "d5":
        print("You hit on target D5!")
    elif hit=="E1" or "e1":
        print("You hit on target E1!")
    elif hit=="E3" or "e3":
       print("You hit on target E3!")
    else:
       print("You missed!")
    r+=1
r = 0
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  First of all, you do not "call" an `if` statement; "call" is a transfer of program flow to a function, not an `if`.  Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Your code is not minimal; this appears to be a short question, perhaps 5 lines.  Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.  Also include what output you get, and what you expect -- not unspecific, general terms of program flow.

Comment: Actually thanks for the question tips but btw I got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the indentation

```
r = 0


while r<15:
    hit = str(input("""A1    A2    A3    A4    A5\n\nB1    B2    B3    B4    B5\n\nC1    C2    C3    C4    
C5\n\nD1    D2    D3    D4    D5\n\nE1    E2    E3    E4    E5\nThis is the board. Pick any co- 
ordinate you want to fire on: """))

    if hit in ("A2", "a2"):
        print("You hit on target A2!")
    elif hit in ("B2", "b2"):
        print("You hit on target B3!")
    elif hit in ("C1", "c1"):
        print("You hit on target C1!")
    elif hit in ("C2", "c2"):
        print("You hit on target C2!")
    elif hit in ("D5","d5"):
        print("You hit on target D5!")
    elif hit in ("E1", "e1"):
        print("You hit on target E1!")
    elif hit in ("E3", "e3"):
       print("You hit on target E3!")
    else:
       print("You missed!")
    r+=1
```

The code that will run inside the loop is executed by the indentation so if your first line inside the loop is not indebted then the following code will not execute as part of the loop.
And to check the `hit` value is equal to one of two options it will be better `in`